# how to set textfield size in grails

Tags: css, grails

I would like to increase the size (width) of the text input fields in my grails application.
I searched main.css and found a textarea entry, where I successfully increased textarea size.

Is there an equivalent for input text fields ? Or How to increase them ?

peter
Dortmund Germany

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

This is a fancy search field where when you click the input text field it expands...

gsp

```
<div class="form-controller" id="s2">
 <g:remoteField  placeholder="${message(code: 'search.navbar.placeholder', default: 'Search ...')}" name="q" class="form-control"  update="searchPanel" paramName="q" url="[controller:'environments', action:'search']"></g:remoteField>
   </div>
```

css

```
#s2 {
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;

}

#s2 input {
    background: url(../images/search/search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color: #bebebe;
   /* width: 150px;*/
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}

#s2 input:focus {
    width: 200px;
     background: url(../images/search/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
    color: #6a6f75;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in main.css:

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 600px;
}
```

It worked for me.